# What is Salesforce development

Tags: javascript, java, salesforce, apex

What is meant by salesforce development? What are the products they are developing? Anyone please help me about this development, I had no idea what they are.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The first thing I want to tell you is that a Salesforce developer need not necessarily work for Salesforce. Like myself, I work on the Salesforce platform, I develop Visualforce pages and code in Apex language for a living. And I do not work for the company “Salesforce” aka SFDC.

Salesforce is a company who provide software solutions on the cloud. They have a SaaS/ CRM platform providing various services. And they also provide a PaaS/ developer platform on which you can build your own applications.

Those professionals who build Salesforce applications across the various PaaS platforms are called Salesforce Developers. You can build applications on:

[Force.com](http://Force.com)

If you want to an idea of what exactly Salesforce development involves, check out this blog which will make you a Salesforce Developer in action:

[Salesforce Developer Tutorial: Get Started With Salesforce Programming | Edureka](http://%20Salesforce%20Developer%20Tutorial:%20Get%20Started%20With%20Salesforce%20Programming%20%7C%20Edureka)